# Vue.js Node.js Axios.js Does not work as expected in documentation

Tags: node.js, vue.js, axios

env :   axios 0.16.2.  node 4.0.8

A simple get  is raising an error when I use:

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000/api/'
url :axios.get('/shoppinglist/s')
```

but it runs well if I only use a full url

```
axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/shoppinglists/'
```

**api.index.js**

```
const axios = require('axios')

const config = {
  timeout: 1000
}

axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000/api/'

export default {

  fetchShoppingLists: () => {
    return axios.get('/shoppinglists/', config)
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('FETCH error: ', error)
      if (error.response) {
        console.log('FETCH error.response: ', error.response)
      } else {
        console.log('Error', error.message)
        console.log(error.config)
      }
      throw error
    })
  }
}
```

**console.log**

```
LOG LOG: 

'FETCH error: ', Error{
config: Object{adapter: null, transformRequest: Object{0: ...}, 
transformResponse: Object{0: ...}, 
timeout: 1000, xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN', xsrfHeaderName: 
'X-XSRF-TOKEN', maxContentLength: -1, 
validateStatus: function validateStatus(status) { ... }, 
headers: Object{Accept: ...}, 
baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/api/', method: 'get', 
url: 'shoppinglists/', 
data: undefined}, 
response: Object{status: 404, config: Object{adapter: ..., transformRequest: ..., transformResponse: ..., timeout: ..., xsrfCookieName: ..., xsrfHeaderName: ..., maxContentLength: ..., validateStatus: ..., headers: ..., baseURL: ..., method: ..., url: ..., data: ...}, data: undefined}}


'FETCH error.response: ', Object{
status: 404, 
config: Object{adapter: null, transformRequest: Object{0: ...}, transformResponse: Object{0: ...}, 
timeout: 1000, xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN', 
xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN', maxContentLength: -1, 
validateStatus: function validateStatus(status) { ... }, 
headers: Object{Accept: ...}, 
baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/api/', 
method: 'get', 
url: 'shoppinglists/', data: undefined
}, 

data: undefined}
```

Answer (score 1):

> A simple get is raising an error when I use:
>
> ```
> axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000/api/'
> url :axios.get('/shoppinglist/')
> ```
>
> but it runs well if I only use a full url
>
> `axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/shoppinglists/'`

Have you tried removing the trailing `/` from your baseURL? e.g. `http://localhost:3000/api`

I would assume its trying `http://localhost:3000/api/` + `/shoppinglists/s` = `http://localhost:3000/api//shoppinglists`

Comment: yes I tried ... same issue. ... 

headers: Object{Accept: ...}, baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/api', method: 'get', url: '/shoppinglists', data: undefined}, data: undefined}

Comment: trying both .. show that my issue is in the difference between sending a full url or a base + url ...

Comment: the only cos which is working is :  import axios from 'axios' and using an ABSOLUTE url. :  axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/shoppinglists/', config)... cannot find why in the scarcde axios doc...

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved ! I discovered the issue looking into :

1/ how axios was sending the request

```
 LOG: 'AXIOS DISPATCH REQUEST 51: ', '{"transformRequest":{},"transformResponse":{},"
 timeout":0,"xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN","xsrfHeaderName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN","maxContentLength":-1,"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"},"baseURL":"http://localhost:3000/",
 "method":"get",
 "url":"http://localhost:3000/shoppinglists"}'
```

2/ how axios-mock-adapter was handling the request

```
function handleRequest(mockAdapter, resolve, reject, config) {
  if (config.baseURL && config.url.substr(0, config.baseURL.length) === config.baseURL) {
     config.url = config.url.slice(config.baseURL ? config.baseURL.length : 0);
  }
  ...
}
```

it's related to the axils-mock-adapter ( used in tests) in which I must used the passed url ( not the baseURL + url)

in my api/index.js

```
  axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000/'

  fetchShoppingLists: () => {
    return axios.get('shoppinglists')
     .catch(error => {
       throw error
     })
  },
```

and in my test spec.js

```
mock.onGet('shoppinglists').reply(() => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
```